# Calling methods inside class to modify list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class in which I collect data to list with the help of wide range of methods (say 23). Every method uses list and could modify it. My question is how can I call (in class, respectively) all methods of class in more generally accepted way?

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = []

    def multiply(self):
        for i in xrange(10):
            self.lst.append(i**2)

    def get_list(self):
        return self.lst
# Calling:
ex = Example()
ex.multiply
print ex.get_list
# What I want is call multiply method inside class and just do this
print ex.get_list
```

Example class illustrates my idea. I know that it is possible to solve my problem through iterating with Example.__dict__values(), calling all methods in one class's method or with inspect module, but I am not sure that there are not more pure-Pythonic ways.

**UPDATE:**

All I want is to collect configuration data for [yapf](https://github.com/google/yapf/blob/master/yapf/yapflib/style.py#L45) formatter.

The main problem is how to call all methods in class - I don't want to implement all configuration analysis of input file in one method. OOP and patterns is my guide.

**UPDATE 2:**
Answer for Jared Goguen. I want to create class to collect data to dictionary and send it to [CreateStyleFromConfig](https://github.com/google/yapf/blob/master/yapf/yapflib/style.py#L257) method.
And when it will done, I want just to get get_style method from class without calling all methods inside it:

```
config = ConfData() # Class which collects all configurations from file
config.get_style()
```

ConfData class contains methods with specific for data name. For example:

```
def align_closing_bracket_with_visual_indent(self):
    # Do some work..
    pass
```

Comment: What are you asking? What is your expected result?

Comment: I think the easiest approach is inspect, unless you also want to define another list or dictionary in your class that contains all the available methods for that class and iterate over that.

Comment: Do you want to sub-class the behavior of list? It's not really clear what you're trying to do. Maybe an example of how you'd want to use your code would help.

Comment: Unless you're absolutely sure the methods in your class can be run in any order, I'd probably have one method that calls them all in the correct order.

Comment: Or, if there is a subset of methods that can be called in any order, you might be able to create a decorator to keep track of them which would allow implementing a `call_relevant_methods` in a natural manner.

Comment: You want to call every single method in your class in order of definition? O.o

Comment: @BiRico, I have changed question.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, the order of calling methods doesn't matter. I just want to collect data - every element of list is pair of tuple.

Comment: @JaredGoguen, could you please give an example?

Comment: Can you provide more explanation and maybe example usage? I'm not going to write up an answer that may not apply to your use-case.

Comment: @JaredGoguen, I have updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I guess there are two potential solution to this, but I don't really like either of them. I think you might be approaching the problem the wrong way.

You could use an external decorator `track` and a class variable `tracker` to keep track of which methods you want to call.

```
def track(tracker):
    def wrapper(func):
        tracker.append(func)
        return func
    return wrapper

class Example:
    tracker = []

    @track(tracker)
    def method_a(self):
        return [('key_a1', 'val_a1'), ('key_a2', 'val_a2')]

    @track(tracker)
    def method_b(self):
        return [('key_b1', 'val_b1'), ('key_b2', 'val_b2')]

    def collect_data(self):
        return dict(tup for method in self.tracker for tup in method(self))

print Example().collect_data()
# {'key_b1': 'val_b1', 'key_b2': 'val_b2', 'key_a1': 'val_a1', 'key_a2': 'val_a2'}
```

With this approach, you can have utility methods in your class that you don't want to call.

Another approach would be to inspect the directory of your class and logically determine which methods you want to call.

```
from inspect import ismethod

class Example:
    def method_a(self):
        return [('key_a1', 'val_a1'), ('key_a2', 'val_a2')]

    def method_b(self):
        return [('key_b1', 'val_b1'), ('key_b2', 'val_b2')]

    def collect_data(self):
        data = {}
        for attr in dir(self):
            if not attr.startswith('_') and attr != 'collect_data':
                possible_method = getattr(self, attr)
                if ismethod(possible_method):
                    data.update(possible_method())
        return data
```

This approach is similar to the one mentioned in your post (i.e. iterating over `__dict__`) and is weak because any instance methods that you *don't* want to call need to start with '_'. You can adapt this approach to use some other naming convention, but it might not be readable to anyone else.

Either of these methods could implement the `collect_data` portion as a super-class, allowing you to create minimal sub-classes. This doesn't really help much with the first approach.

```
class MethodTracker(object):
    def collect_data(self):
        return dict(tup for method in self.tracker for tup in method(self))

class Example(MethodTracker):
    tracker = []

    @track(tracker)
    def method_a(self):
        return [('key_a1', 'val_a1'), ('key_a2', 'val_a2')]

    @track(tracker)
    def method_b(self):
        return [('key_b1', 'val_b1'), ('key_b2', 'val_b2')]
```

With the second approach, the resulting sub-class is minimal. Also, you can do a little reflection to allow the super-class to have utility methods that don't start with '_'.

```
from inspect import ismethod

class MethodTracker(object):
    def collect_data(self):
        data = {}
        for attr in dir(self):
            if not attr.startswith('_') and not hasattr(MethodTracker, attr):
                possible_method = getattr(self, attr)
                if ismethod(possible_method):
                    data.update(possible_method())
        return data

    def decoy_method(self):
        return 'This is not added to data.'

class Example(MethodTracker):
    def method_a(self):
        return [('key_a1', 'val_a1'), ('key_a2', 'val_a2')]

    def method_b(self):
        return [('key_b1', 'val_b1'), ('key_b2', 'val_b2')]
```